# Animals still escape their pens

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After I downloaded the newest Minecraft patch the animals are still escaping their pens. What do I have to do in order to keep my animals from escaping? They seem to be glitching out of the pens. How can I prevent this?

Below is a video of how my pens are set up.

All types of animals are escaping their pens. The pens are just constructed using fences in a 4x6 block. I'm on Minecraft version  1.6.4.  The cow in the video glitched into the solid dirt enclosure.

Comment: We're going to need more information to solve your problem here. How is your animal pen set up? What version of Minecraft are you currently on? Is it happening with chickens only, or are other animals escaping?

Comment: I can't speak for the people who downvoted, but your question as it is now assumes that the whole "mobs glitching through fences" thing was fixed, which, looking through the changelog, does not appear to be the case. Also, Minecraft 1.6.4 includes *all* bugfixes from *all* previous updates, so if it was fixed, there should be no technical reason for this happening. I suggest you change your question a bit to ask for suggestions on how to prevent this from happening, rather than asking if an update will fix it.

Comment: This occurs in 1.6.2. I know - I've slaughtered many escapee sheep for their disloyalty. The slower your rig, the more it can happen, because it's due to a long-standing bug where entities are loaded (and move around) before blocks are, so the slower your game processes chunkloading, the more time animals have to run around and escape before the fences load.

Comment: Video in question is dead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This is a bug that still exists in the game](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-2025). Clearly, I suppose. Point is, your version of Minecraft has nothing to do with it.

I have seen this problem many times, and it seems to be related to fences and reloading the world after it has been unloaded. One solution to your chicken escapee problem could be to dig a two-deep pit for your animals to live in.

[image: Don't they look so happy?]

...but there's a problem. When you replace the fences your animals have glitched into with solid blocks, you have some slight suffocation problems (same bug). So that's no good without some slight adjustments.

I tried an old method using water, however, animals are somehow more broken now, and sit at the bottom of the water streams and drown.

So I tried another approach: I used slabs for the bottom layer of wall instead of dirt blocks. They'll still keep your animals inside, even if you relog, and with minimal casualties (occasionally, I'd get a few baby pigs suffocate when I relogged, but nowhere near as consistently as without using slabs.

[image: Saddled pig ranch, no escapees]

However, I have found some weird behavior using slabs. You can use any other transparent block, but, since apparently baby pigs are less than a half block tall now, you cannot use slabs. Also, if you wish to contain cows, you will need 2 layers of transparent blocks. I used glowstone in this case.

[image: Updated image]

***SCIENCE!***

Comment: When this was particularly common with chickens (yeah, Mojang have tried to fix this multiple times, and often made it worse!), the common advice was to use glass for enclosures to minimise suffocation.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, glass should work as well. I just chose slabs. You could use pistons for all I care. As long as it's transparent.

Comment: I have just found some weird behavior as a consequence of choosing slabs, so I am updating my answer as such presently.

Answer (score 0):

I dug out caves two blocks underground underneath the pens and dug underneath the pens to make them fall in. I use doors to access the underground pens. If you want grass for the sheep to grow their wool back either lead the grass down until it starts spreading or use silk touch. Hope it helped.